# Proof that 6 divides $a \in \mathbb{Z}, a(a^2 - 7)$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, modular-arithmetic, divisibility, alternative-proof

I am trying to prove a question from my tutorial sheet, is this an acceptable proof?

Six cases exist:
$$a,k \in \mathbb{Z}, a(a^2 - 7) = 6k
\\\text{Proof:}\\
a = 0 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 = 0 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 - 1\mod 6 = 5 \longrightarrow a(a^2 - 7) = 0\mod 6\\
a = 1 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 = 1 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 - 1\mod 6 = 0 \longrightarrow a(a^2 - 7) = 0\mod 6\\
a = 2 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 = 4 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 - 1\mod 6 = 3 \longrightarrow a(a^2 - 7) = 0\mod 6\\
a = 3 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 = 3 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 - 1\mod 6 = 2 \longrightarrow a(a^2 - 7) = 0\mod 6\\
a = 4 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 = 4 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 - 1\mod 6 = 3 \longrightarrow a(a^2 - 7) = 0\mod 6\\
a = 5 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 = 1 \mod 6 \longrightarrow a^2 - 1\mod 6 = 0 \longrightarrow a(a^2 - 7) = 0\mod 6\\
$$
Therefore, since for all $a$, $a(a^2 - 7) = 0 \mod 6$, $6$ divides $a(a^2 - 7)$.

Is there an easier proof, or a better way to lay this out via $LaTeX$?

Comment: Arrows are sometimes used incorrectly. But cases is a reasonable approach. We do most of the cases. If $a\equiv 0\pmod{6}$, then $a(a^2-7)\equiv 0\pmod{6}$. If $a\equiv \pm 1\pmod{6}$, then $a^2\equiv 1\pmod{6}$, and therefore $a^2-7\equiv 0\pmod{6}$, and $a(a^2-7)\equiv 0\pmod{6}$. If $a\equiv \pm 2\pmod{6}$, then $a^2-7\equiv -3\pmod{6}$, and therefore $a(a^2-7)\equiv (\pm 2)(-3)\equiv 0\pmod{6}$. It is nice to replace the ugly $7$ by $1$ at the start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$a(a^2-7)= a(a^2-1)-6a=(a-1)a(a+1)-6a$$

Now the first term being the product of $3$ consecutive integers is divisible by $3!$

Comment: Wow, just wow. I can't believe that I overlooked a one line proof! Thank you for that!